# Interaction between two objects

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I would like to know if blender allows to establish an interaction between two different meshes. I've tried the example of soft body, with the jelly cube, etc. but that is not what I need. For example, if I want to simulate the interaction of forces between a ball and a elastic surface (no cloth), could I do that in blender?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Anyway, it´s possible with bullet physics right now (softbody-rigidbody interaction). So might come with 2.8.. who knows. You could use the game engine in the meantime. It has better bullet support.